# NSDictionary, how to store and read enum values?

Tags: ios, enums, swift, nsdictionary

How can I store and read enum values in a NSDictionary in Swift.

I defined a few types

```
enum ActionType {
    case Person
    case Place
    case Activity    
}
```

**Write** enum to dictionary

```
myDictionary.addObject(["type":ActionType.Place])
```

*"AnyObject does not have a member named key"*

**Read**

```
var type:ActionType = myDictionary.objectForKey("type") as ActionType
```

*"Type 'ActionType' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"*

I also tried wrapping the ActionType as NSNumber/Int which didn't quite work. Any advice on how to correctly store and read enum values in NSDictionaries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's complaint because you cannot save values type to NSDictionary (enums is a value type).
You have to wrap it to a NSNumber but remember to call toRaw on this enum, try this:

```
enum ActionType : Int {
    case Person
    case Place
    case Activity
}
var myDictionary = NSDictionary(object:NSNumber(integer: ActionType.Place.toRaw()), forKey:"type")
```

// Extended

This is how to access it step by step:

```
let typeAsNumber = myDictionary["type"] as? NSNumber
let tmpInt = typeAsNumber?.integerValue

let typeValue = ActionType.fromRaw(tmpInt!)
println(typeValue!.toRaw())
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for the explanation. What's the best way to turn the dictionary value back into the enum? I tried         var typeValue:ActionType = (myDictionary.objectForKey("type") as NSNumber).intValue … which didn't work

Comment: @BerndPlontsch please see extended answer.

Comment: I though dictionaries and arrays accept any object as values. This sounds like property lists' object restrictions.

Comment: @Rivera dictionaries and arrays accept any object but NSDictionaries and NSArrays accept just objects, not primitive values.